# Extracting Proper Dimensions With Dplyr Pipeline

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pipeline

Here is a quick snapshot of the dataframe I'm working with:
[image]

I'm trying to extract out the top player per team with the highest "PER".  My best guess is:

```
test = season_advanced_stats %>%
  filter(Tm != "TOT" & MP > 200) %>%
  select(Player, Tm, PER) %>%
  group_by(Tm) %>%
  top_n(n=1)
```

Unfortunately, the dimensions are off and they are 31 X 3 instead of 30 X 3 (there are 30 unique teams in the NBA).  When I use that pipeline it appears that it isn't actually grouping by team since Philadelphia shows up twice and I think that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Show the output for `unique(season_advanced_stats$Tm)`? Also, you never `arrange(desc(PER))` after grouping by `Tm`

Comment: Please include the data rather than a picture of it. `dput(head(season_advanced_stats))` might be enough to make your problem reproducible

Comment: After I used arrange it illuminated why there was 31 teams instead of 30, Philadelphia has two players with the same PER value of 24.1, hence they both show up.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I used arrange it illuminated why there was 31 teams instead of 30, Philadelphia has two players with the same PER value of 24.1, hence they both show up. Thanks!!

[image]